# Get Wordpress excerpt in list of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a custom **WordPress** widget/plugin to return the title and excerpt of a post within a permalink to the article. I am almost there but am struggling with getting the excerpt to show. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

    $categories = get_the_category($recent["ID"]);

    $excerpt = apply_filters('get_the_excerpt', $recent->post_excerpt);

    echo '<a class="m-item  diet-and-nutrition" href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" > <div class="pix"></div><div class="eyebrow"> <b>' . $categories[0]->name . '</b> / '.   $recent["post_date"].'</div> <figure>' .  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'full') . '<figcaption class="center"> <span> <h4>'.  $recent["post_title"].'</h4> </span> <span> <p>'.  $excerpt .'</p> </span> </figcaption> </figure> </a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an array so:

```
$recent->post_excerpt
```

should be:

```
$recent['post_excerpt'];
```